# Implementing a simple associative map in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary, constructor, associative

in this period I am learning Haskell but I have problems solving a simple exercise.

I would like to write a simple associative map data structure to exercise myself.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
-- It represents a simple ordered couple in the form (key, value)
data Element a b = Element (a, b)
    deriving (Show)

-- It represents a (unordered) list of elements in the form (key, value)
data Dictionary a b = Dictionary [Element a b]
    deriving (Show)

-- It represents a simple dictionary which will be used for my tests
t :: Dictionary Char Int
t = Dictionary [Element ('a', 1), Element ('b', 2), Element ('a', 3)]
```

Now I am trying to write a simple method to return a list of couples in the form (a, b). I am doing it to exercise myself and to provide a simple function which would be useful for the other methods (find, etc.).

I have written this piece of code but I know it's wrong:

```
couples :: Dictionary a b -> [(a, b)]
couples (Dictionary t) = [(k , v) | (k, v) <- t]
```

The problem is that obviously "t" is not a list of couples: it's composed by a list of elements which are composed by a type constructor "Element" followed by an ordered couple.

How could I "get rid" of the "Element" type constructor? I have no idea...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just as an aside, it's called "tuples", not couples, but the pronunciation rhymes with couples.  Not trying to nitpick, but this can help avoid confusion.

Comment: How much leeway do you have in the implementation?  I think there are simpler ways of doing this.

Comment: I understand that you want to practice, but just FYI: in Data.List there is a function `lookup :: Eq k => k -> [(k,v)] -> Maybe v` which already does this.

Comment: Thank you. In my language we use to call "tuples" ordered list of a generic number of elements and "ordered couples" ordered list of 2 elements.

Comment: Yes, I am going to study the library, too. I just wanted to write a simple dictionary for exercise :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the Element constructor in the pattern-match.

```
couples :: Dictionary a b -> [(a, b)]
couples (Dictionary t) = [(k , v) | (Element (k, v)) <- t]
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I thought I could do pattern matching just in the left part of the equations. I have to exercise in these kind of things.

Comment: @JohnQ you should also accept Dirk's answer since it answers your question

Comment: Yes, of course! I don't have much experience with StackOverflow. Now I have accepted it as the answer :)